# hanging ADD FOREIGN KEY: is there a workaround?

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos-7

Now I'm sorta PostgreSQL DBA/dev...
and faced the problem that looks a well known one:

```
alter table assessment -- quite simple new table: (event int, value bool)
  add constraint assessment_event_fk
    foreign key (event)
    references rtls(id) -- it refs the primary key integer field
```

Adding `not valid` (in useless hope to `validate` it later on) is of no help either.

Yes, I know, it hangs (the `rtls` table is about 2M records now).
And one have to `pg_dump` the base, edit SQL, and load it back.
I saw this "advise" in posts since circa 2003...

**It's 9.2.18** from standard deployment on CentOS 7, if it matters (**it does!**).

I cannot believe that it stuck here over decade...
**What should I consider to work it around?**

Use sorta `check` for `exists (select id from rtls where id=?)` ???
No way:

```
vad=> alter table assessment add constraint assessment_event_fk check(exists (select rtls.id from rtls where rtls.id=event));
ERROR:  cannot use subquery in check constraint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just upgrade to 9.6.**

My script to upgrade here: https://pastebin.com/PzcatZaQ (yes, I had to upgrade several nodes -- dev/test farm)